# MYSQL - Swap or ReOrder the values of 2 or more rows by group

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this table:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+order_no + item_name  +  group_no +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   1     +  item1     +     0     +
+   2     +  item2     +     1     +
+   3     +  item3     +     1     +
+   4     +  item4     +     1     +
+   5     +  item5     +     2     +
+   6     +  item6     +     2     +
+   7     +  item7     +     3     +
+   8     +  item8     +     3     +
+   9     +  item9     +     0     +
+   10    +  item10    +     4     +
+   11    +  item11    +     4     +
+   12    +  item12    +     4     +
+   13    +  item13    +     4     +
+   14    +  item14    +     5     +
+   15    +  item15    +     0     +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Note:
order_no is not auto_increment.

I want to swap order_no based on group_no. Example, if I swap the order_no of group1 and group4 this will be the new table.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+order_no + item_name  +  group_no +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   1     +  item1     +     0     +
+   11    +  item2     +     1     +
+   12    +  item3     +     1     +
+   13    +  item4     +     1     +
+   6     +  item5     +     2     +
+   7     +  item6     +     2     +
+   8     +  item7     +     3     +
+   9     +  item8     +     3     +
+   10    +  item9     +     0     +
+   2     +  item10    +     4     +
+   3     +  item11    +     4     +
+   4     +  item12    +     4     +
+   5     +  item13    +     4     +
+   14    +  item14    +     5     +
+   15    +  item15    +     0     +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**Is there a way to accomplish this?**

Comment: Why is group `0` spread out and not on adjacent rows like the other groups?

Comment: if group_no is 0, it means that it doesn't have a group.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by resetting `order_no` using variables.  The idea is to re-sort the table and just assign sequential numbers.

```
update table t cross join
             (select min(case when group_no = 1 then order_no end) as on1,
                     min(case when group_no = 4 then order_no end) as on4,
                     @ordernum := 0
              from t
             ) vals       
    set order_no = (@ordernum := @ordernum + 1)
    order by (case when group_no = 1 then on4
                   when group_no = 4 then on1
                   else order_no
              end),
             order_no;
```

The first part of the `order by` swaps the groups.  The additional sort by `order_no` is to keep the original order.